# How can a column's data type be safely reduced from NVARCHAR(max)?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2019, datatypes, varchar

My biggest table owes most of its size to a stupid `NVARCHAR(max)` column that I wager could easily be `NVARCHAR(4000)` or smaller. What steps can I take to become confident that this change is safe to make and to make it safely?

Comment: Talk to whomever created it/uses it in the App and understand the use cases and get their buyoff on changing it.

Comment: make a select that checks the length of all rows of that column and output then once that are bigger. then you need to find the common denominator that can reduce the size to 4000

Comment: RE: "owes most of its size" is this the motivation for making the change? Changing from `NVARCHAR(max)` to `NVARCHAR(4000)` won't reduce storage requirements if all data fits into that - as this depends on the size of the data not the declared max

Comment: But memory grants are based on declared column lengths so worthwhile from that perspective.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes and you're right, except for [this technicality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks): "_Each non-null varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) column requires 24 bytes of additional fixed allocation, which counts against the 8,060-byte row limit during a sort operation._".

Comment: If the value is small enough to fit into a non max datatype and you don't have "large value types out of row" table option then it can be stored in row with no space needed for any pointer. Off row storage can also happen for non max variable width columns. There are reasons for avoiding `max` unnecessarily but not clear what your motivation is here.

Comment: @MartinSmith My entire motivation is "this is the biggest table in my database and that column is bigger than it needs to be, so maybe I should make it smaller".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/04/video-altering-datatypes-with-almost-no-downtime/).

Be careful when you pass from `NVARCHAR(max)` to `NVARCHAR(4000)` because everything longer than 4000 will be cut.

Just curious, what are you storing in that `NVARCHAR(max)`?

Logs?

In that case the solution is not passing to `NVARCHAR(4000)` but storing the logs into files outside the database.

Comment: The column is just for metadata.

Comment: Awesome, but: "_Just a couple of gotchas: it only works with row compression (not page), and it **only works for upsizing datatypes, not downsizing**._"

Comment: ah, dammit. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To change from nvarchar(MAX) to nvarchar(4000), You have to be sure that nothing is not longer than 4000 character.
So, to do that you can create expression which count the value length of that column. If all lengths is smaller than 4001, you can change it safely.

Be careful and test first on test or stage environment.
please get a look on these links.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

[https://www.quora.com/Are-the-limits-of-varchar-8000-and-nvarchar-4000-because-of-the-SQL-server-page-size-8KB-8192-Bytes-If-not-what-else-is-the-reason#:~:text=NVARCHAR%20data%20type%20stores%20variable,of%20the%20data%20being%20stored](https://www.quora.com/Are-the-limits-of-varchar-8000-and-nvarchar-4000-because-of-the-SQL-server-page-size-8KB-8192-Bytes-If-not-what-else-is-the-reason#:%7E:text=NVARCHAR%20data%20type%20stores%20variable,of%20the%20data%20being%20stored).